# Duality pairing with reversed order?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $X'$ be its dual. Then, in my PDE course and thus far in my mathematical life, the duality pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is defined as $$\langle f, x\rangle:=f(x)$$ for $f\in X'$ and $x\in X$.

However, all of a sudden in my course my lecturer started writing $\langle x, f \rangle$ for some element $x\in X$ and $f\in X'$. My guess is that this is just the duality pairing again, i.e. $$\langle x, f\rangle=f(x)$$ too, but I do not know if this reversed notation is also in use and moreover why one would choose to all of a sudden mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x\in X$, you can obtain an element of $X''$ by defining $J(x) :X' \to \mathbb{K}$ by $[J(x)](f) := f(x)$. This is a continuous linear functional on $X'$ with norm $\|x\|$, so it is indeed an element of $X''$. From there, you obtain an isometric embedding $J$ of $X$ into $X''$ defined by associating each $x\in X$ with a corresponding element of $X''$ as defined above.

The notation $\langle x,f\rangle$ above can be used in that manner to allow you to use an element $x$ of $X$ as a continuous linear functional on $X'$. This notation emphasises being able switch between evaluating $f\in X'$ at the point $x\in X$, or being able to evaluate the element of $X''$ associated with $x$, which is $J(x)$, at the continuous linear functional $f\in X'$.

Comment: I see, so it is basically the duality pairing between $X'$ and its dual $X''$, which gives us the same result in the way you described. This is pretty neat, thank you so much, now this makes sense!